# Connect internal signal to output port in MyHDL module

Tags: myhdl

Considering the following example (a simple 8-bit counter), is there a simpler way to connect the internal `s_count` signal to the `o_count` port?

```
def counter(i_clk, i_reset, o_count):

    """ A free-running 8-bit counter with a synchronous reset """

    s_count = Signal(intbv(0)[8:])

    @always(i_clk.posedge)
    def count():
        if i_reset == 1:
            s_count.next = 0
        else:        
            s_count.next = s_count + 1

    @always_comb
    def outputs():
        o_count.next = s_count        

    return count, outputs
```

Of course, I could directly increment `o_count` in the `count` function but this translates to an `inout` port in the generated VHDL module, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect directly incrementing o_count is an acceptable solution.

Indeed, it translates to an inout because you cannot read output ports in VHDL.

However, this will only happen when you convert this module as a top module. It is likely that this is a small submodule however. In that case, the hierarchy is flattened out and o_count will be an internal signal.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. It is indeed a submodule that I tried to convert stand-alone to see what the VHDL looks like.